# find big files with recursion in mac

Tags: java, macos, recursion, intellij-idea

I'm programming on a Mac using the IntelliJ IDEA, and I'm writing a program to find big files(1GB) using recursion. Here's the code that I wrote so far.

```java
public class Exercise05 {
    public static MyFilter myFilter = new MyFilter();
    public static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("/");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        findBigFile(file);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println(endTime - startTime);
        System.out.println(count);

    }

    public static void findBigFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {

        if (file.isFile()) {
            if (myFilter.bigFile(file)) {
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                System.out.println(file.length());
                count++;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                if (file.listFiles().length > 0) {
                    File[] files = file.listFiles();
                    for (File file1 : files) {
                        findBigFile(file1);
                    }
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyFilter {
    public boolean bigFile(File file) {
        if (file.length() > (1024 * 1024 * 1024)) {
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of my results

```
/.DocumentRevisions-V100
/.fseventsd
/.Spotlight-V100
/.Trashes
/Applications/.Wineskin2
/Applications/AliWangwang.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Resources/fr.lproj/fr.lproj
/Applications/AliWangwang.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Resources/fr_CA.lproj
/Applications/AliWangwang.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fr.lproj/fr.lproj
/Applications/AliWangwang.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fr_CA.lproj
/Applications/AliWangwang.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/fr.lproj/fr.lproj
/Applications/AliWangwang.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/fr_CA.lproj
/Applications/leanote.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Frameworks
/Applications/leanote.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Libraries/Libraries
```

I debugged the program and found that some files returned `false` when `File.isFile()` was evaluated, which is strange. They are files not folders, and this cause the program to execute the else statement. Why is it doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "performed the else statements"? Which files? If you're really just asking why `File.isFile` is returning `false` unexpectedly sometimes, it would help if you'd *just* ask that question, with concrete examples of the files involved.

Comment: I'm just asking why `File.isFile` is returning `false`.

Comment: See @Burkhard 's answer. You'll need to investigate while those files are "abnormal"

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc states:

```
public boolean isFile()

Tests whether the file denoted by this abstract pathname is a normal file. A file is normal if it is not a directory and, in addition, satisfies other system-dependent criteria. Any non-directory file created by a Java application is guaranteed to be a normal file.

Where it is required to distinguish an I/O exception from the case that the file is not a normal file, or where several attributes of the same file are required at the same time, then the Files.readAttributes method may be used.

Returns:
    true if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists and is a normal file; false otherwise
```

So in your case, the file is probably not a *normal* file.

Edit:
Since isDirectory() does only return true if it is a directory, you should invert the if else and use file.isDirectory() instead.

Comment: So how to define a  normal file?

Comment: It is system-dependent. Using isDirectory() might be safer.

Comment: I tried your advice and it became much better.Some directories throw a exception.I guess it's the reason of access permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Convert you file size and then compare to get the actual big file in a folder.

```
double bytes = file.length();
double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
```

Comment: Be careful with that. If it is a directory. "The return value is unspecified if this pathname denotes a directory. "

Comment: then just do a cross check like `file.isDirectory()` then proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the `File.isDirectory()` instead, and see if it returns similar results.